# A phrase for the opposite of "getting over" something

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, antonyms

I was speaking to a friend today.
I jokingly told her: "Yes, I should speak Spanish, but I don't. Get over it."

She attempted a witty response:
"Get over it? I am. It's like *I was never under it*."

She was not satisfied with the use of *"under"* in this comeback however. What she intended to do was to state the opposite of "to get over" something in a quick, jesting manner, but she submitted to me that there does not actually exist a clever and short enough phrase to make an effective comeback of that sort with respect to me not knowing Spanish.

I told her that I bet this stack exchange can provide an acceptably witty and short variation of that comeback. Can it?

I can think of some examples where a similar "reversal-of-phrase" comeback is made successfully:

Example 1:
Person 1: "You really need to forget about your ex-boyfriend/girlfriend and move on."
Person 2: "Forget him/her? It's like I never even met him/her."

Example 2 (this is different but maybe plays on the same tone):
Person 1: "Just pretend like this conversation never happened."
Person 2: "*What* conversation never happened?"

Example 1+2 (for the lols, maybe unrealistic):
Person 1: "You really need to forget about your ex-boyfriend/girlfriend and move on."
Person 2: "Who are you talking about?"

Comment: Since you are *getting over it* in the sense of getting over a cold, one first *comes down* with a cold, and then one *gets over it*.  But "*Get over it? I have.  It's like I never came down with it.*" probably is too obtuse for general use.

Comment: *"never came down with it"* sounds weird, but it could be phrased **"went down from it"** or **"gone down..."**. That also relates to *"being down"* as in being depressed.

Comment: Responses to "Get over it":  "The ladder's already back in the shed." "I'll run right home & get my hiking boots." "Shall I hire a sherpa?" -OR- "Get over what?"

Comment: [There are many kinds of opposite](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/119235/4972)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Over* it?

I'm observing it from high altitude!

Believe me, if I was any more over it, I'd be in geo-stationary orbit.

Answer (score 1):

She could say "When have I asked you to learn Spanish?"

as if She is so over worrying about it that she forgot she asked in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Filling in the blank in the following construction might produce something more appropriate:

"...? If I was any MORE over it I ___________."

But my favorite is still:

> Get over it?  Believe me, if I was any LESS over it I might just give
>   a damn!

(or "... I might actually care" in situations where even light swearing wouldn't be acceptable)

Answer (score 0):

I take it the conversation between you and your friend went something like this:

> Friend: You should learn to speak Spanish.
>
> You: Yes, I should speak Spanish, but I don't. Get over it.

At that point, your friend could have used the popular (nowadays) phrase *"I'm just saying."* to indicate that her first comment wasn't a big deal (and so there's nothing to get over).

Here's an [article](http://psychcentral.com/lib/defending-against-im-just-saying-and-other-verbal-annoyances/00012762) that discusses when people use the phrase "I'm just saying.":

> Brooke used the expression “I’m just saying” after making an off-putting remark, conveniently absolving herself of responsibility for the affront. This tagline is a handy conversational tool: It serves as a free pass for the speaker to say anything and then negate any ill intent.
>
> [...]
>
> Still, this phrase may also be used more literally, without any hidden agenda, when someone has an unexpected negative reaction to a truly innocuous remark which leaves the speaker feeling unfairly attacked or exposed. In such cases “I’m just saying” expresses honest frustration and is intended in rightful self-defense, conveying: “That was an innocent comment – so chill!”