# What is the most suitable antonym for the word loud?

Tags: vocabulary, antonyms, conversation

In terms of talking, what is the opposite of a loud voice?

For example, when someone is talking and I can not hear them properly, how can I say to them that their voice is very "opposite to loud"?

Is "your voice is very low/quiet/soft" correct?

Comment: Have you checked for antonyms of loud in a dictionary? Which one do you think is most suitable?

Comment: @KillingTime yes, i got quiet, soft. But it does not seem convincing to me.

Comment: Whisper, murmur or synonyms thereof...

Comment: "Your voice is very quiet/soft" gets the meaning across. You could also ask them to speak more loudly or to 'speak up'.

Comment: Try "Your voice is inaudible" or "You are inaudible" ....

Comment: I don't know why people always downvote questions without commenting. Whoever downvoted this question, can you please point out my mistakes so that I can avoid them in the future? Or is it because my question is too silly?

Comment: It is possible another user down-voted for 'lack of basic research', which in this case would be a lookup in a dictionary.

Comment: Consider: [Webster Thesaurus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/loud) As John Lawler indicates below, the concept of "opposite" is usually  relative to the context, and  possibly even an artificial construct.  Why do humans so often  see opposites in simple things like 'up and down', when in space such a thing is irrelevant?

Comment: Please show us how you wish to use the word -- give us the context and a sample sentence.  Review how to ask a well-posed question.  If you reshape your question I'll be happy to remove my close vote.

Answer (score 6):

*Antonym* is a concept that's widely misunderstood. It involves [negation](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf), always a slippery concept, and supposes that there are pairs of opposed words X and Y, where X means *not Y*, and Y means *not X*. Like *high* and *low* or *right* and *left*. But there aren't that many.

There is no such thing as "**the** antonym for the word *loud*", because

1. Not every word has an antonym. Most don't, in fact.
2. Some words have many antonyms. *Small* has dozens, for instance.
3. There are many dimensions in which opposition may occur.

In the case of *loud*, one could be referring to excess noise, where *silent* or *quiet* would be opposites. Or one could be referring to machine noise or animal noises or human speech or music, each with their own stable of words implying aural phenomena. Or it could be referring to volume, and that's a scale with a number of words on it, usually with vertical displacement (*high* vs *low*). And then there's the metaphorical uses -- *loud clothing* is opposed by *conventional* or *subdued*, for instance. And one could go on.

And one could do the same for *synonym*, as far as that goes. The point is that meaning is not a simple matter; meaning doesn't come from dictionaries, and opposites and equivalents are not a simple matter of looking things up.